# How do you get the operand data type using idapython?

Tags: idapython

I know I can set the operand data type of my disassembly using functions such as **OpBinary**, **OpOctal**,**OpDecimal**, etc.

Now, I'm trying to get the current operand data type of my disassembly instead.
For example:

- mov     eax, 200 should return **decimal**
- mov     eax, 0C8h should return **hex**
- mov     eax, 11001000b should return **binary**
- and so on.

**GetOpType** can get the instruction operand type but not the operand data type.
Is there a function to get the operand data type instead?

Answer (score 2):

It seems I can use the following MACROS together with **GetFlags**:

- **isDec1**
- **isHex1**
- **isBin1**